# Preview package error

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, mactex, preview

I'm running into an error using the preview package.  The output below is from SageMath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\oddsidemargin 0.0in
\evensidemargin 0.0in
\textwidth 6.45in
\topmargin 0.0in
\headheight 0.0in
\headsep 0.0in
\textheight 9.0in

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\Bold{Z}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\Bold{N}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\Bold{R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\Bold{C}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\Bold{Q}}
\newcommand{\QQbar}{\overline{\QQ}}
\newcommand{\GF}[1]{\Bold{F}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Zp}[1]{\Bold{Z}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Qp}[1]{\Bold{Q}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Zmod}[1]{\ZZ/#1\ZZ}
\newcommand{\CDF}{\Bold{C}}
\newcommand{\CIF}{\Bold{C}}
\newcommand{\CLF}{\Bold{C}}
\newcommand{\RDF}{\Bold{R}}
\newcommand{\RIF}{\Bold{I} \Bold{R}}
\newcommand{\RLF}{\Bold{R}}
\newcommand{\Bold}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{page}
\begin{document}\begin{page}$\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{cv0}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv0}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv0}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv1}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv2}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv3}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv3}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv3}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv4}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv5}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv5}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv5}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv6}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv6}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv6}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv7}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv8}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv8}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv8}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv9}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cfv9}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{clv9}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv0v5}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1v2}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv1v6}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv2v3}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv2v7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv3v4}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv3v8}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv4v9}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv5v7}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv5v8}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv6v8}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv6v9}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{cv7v9}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
%
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv0,fill=cfv0,text=clv0,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$0$},x=2.5cm,y=5.0cm]{v0}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv1,fill=cfv1,text=clv1,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$1$},x=0.0cm,y=3.0902cm]{v1}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv2,fill=cfv2,text=clv2,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$2$},x=0.9549cm,y=0.0cm]{v2}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv3,fill=cfv3,text=clv3,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$3$},x=4.0451cm,y=0.0cm]{v3}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv4,fill=cfv4,text=clv4,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$4$},x=5.0cm,y=3.0902cm]{v4}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv5,fill=cfv5,text=clv5,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$5$},x=2.5cm,y=3.618cm]{v5}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv6,fill=cfv6,text=clv6,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$6$},x=1.25cm,y=2.6631cm]{v6}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv7,fill=cfv7,text=clv7,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$7$},x=1.7275cm,y=1.118cm]{v7}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv8,fill=cfv8,text=clv8,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$8$},x=3.2725cm,y=1.118cm]{v8}
\Vertex[style={minimum size=1.0cm,draw=cv9,fill=cfv9,text=clv9,shape=circle},LabelOut=false,L=\hbox{$9$},x=3.75cm,y=2.6631cm]{v9}
%
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv0v1,},](v0)(v1)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv0v4,},](v0)(v4)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv0v5,},](v0)(v5)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv1v2,},](v1)(v2)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv1v6,},](v1)(v6)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv2v3,},](v2)(v3)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv2v7,},](v2)(v7)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv3v4,},](v3)(v4)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv3v8,},](v3)(v8)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv4v9,},](v4)(v9)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv5v7,},](v5)(v7)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv5v8,},](v5)(v8)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv6v8,},](v6)(v8)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv6v9,},](v6)(v9)
\Edge[lw=0.1cm,style={color=cv7v9,},](v7)(v9)
%
\end{tikzpicture}$\end{page}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this TeX file fails as is, but is successful when the lines

```
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{page}
```

are commented out (along with the `\begin{page}` and `\end{page}`.  I'm using MacTeX and have even tried reinstalling the preview package from CTAN.

I suspected a conflict with TikZ, and the following MWE **does** work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{page}
\begin{document}
\begin{page}
Test
\end{page}
\end{document}
```

How does one get around the conflict with TikZ without deleting either TikZ or preview from the equation?  Also, is this conflict new, because this sort of file (i.e., graph output from SageMath) used to compile properly?

The log file is (partially) shown below.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.9.28)  30 SEP 2022 08:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Untitled.tex
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

<snip>

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks21
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
\stockwidth=\dimen148
\stockheight=\dimen149
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen150
\Gin@req@width=\dimen151
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup6
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks22
\inpenc@posthook=\toks23
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks24
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen152
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen153

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box53

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyshi/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2020/11/18 v4.00 EveryShipout Package
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
Package: pgf 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks25
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks26

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks27
))
\pgf@x=\dimen154
\pgf@y=\dimen155
\pgf@xa=\dimen156
\pgf@ya=\dimen157
\pgf@xb=\dimen158
\pgf@yb=\dimen159
\pgf@xc=\dimen160
\pgf@yc=\dimen161
\pgf@xd=\dimen162
\pgf@yd=\dimen163
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count271
\c@pgf@countb=\count272
\c@pgf@countc=\count273
\c@pgf@countd=\count274
\t@pgf@toka=\toks28
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks29
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks30
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count275

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count276
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count277
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmath.code.tex
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen164
\pgfmath@count=\count278
\pgfmath@box=\box54
\pgfmath@toks=\toks31
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks32
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks33
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex)))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count279
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfint.code.tex)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen165
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen166
\pgf@picminy=\dimen167
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen168
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen169
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen170
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen171
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen172
\pgf@xx=\dimen173
\pgf@xy=\dimen174
\pgf@yx=\dimen175
\pgf@yy=\dimen176
\pgf@zx=\dimen177
\pgf@zy=\dimen178
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen179
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen180
) (/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen181
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen182
) (/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfpic=\box55
\pgf@hbox=\box56
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box57
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count280
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen183
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoretransformations.code.
tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen184
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen185
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen186
) (/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.t
ex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
) (/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen187
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@max=\dimen188
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count281
\pgf@shadingcount=\count282
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box58
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
) (/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box59
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen189
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen190
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen191
\pgffor@skip=\dimen192
\pgffor@stack=\toks34
\pgffor@toks=\toks35
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.
tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count283
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen193
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen194
\tikz@lasty=\dimen195
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen196
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen197
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen198
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen199
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen256
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen257
\tikz@figbox=\box60
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box61
\tikz@tempbox=\box62
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box63
\tikztreelevel=\count284
\tikznumberofchildren=\count285
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count286
\tikz@fig@count=\count287

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count288
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count289
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count290
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count291

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-graph/tkz-graph.sty
2021/01/20 v 2.00 tkz-graph.sty
Package: tkz-graph 2021/01/20 2.00 base for graphs
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks36
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks37
)
\XKV@depth=\count292
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\arrowsize=\dimen258
))
\c@tkz@gr@a=\count293
\c@tkz@gr@b=\count294
\c@tkz@gr@c=\count295
\c@tkz@gr@e=\count296
\c@tkz@gr@d=\count297
\c@tkz@gr@p=\count298
\c@tkz@gr@i=\count299
\c@tkz@gr@n=\count300
\c@tkz@gr@ta=\count301
\c@tkz@gr@tb=\count302
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-berge/tkz-berge.sty
Package: tkz-berge 2011/06/01 2.00 tkz-berge for named graphs
\c@tkz@bg@cnt=\count303
\c@tkza@tmp=\count304
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.
code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.c
ode.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.
tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.t
ex
File: pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.co
de.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryshapes.symbols.cod
e.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.cod
e.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code
.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.c
ode.tex
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.co
de.tex))
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.
code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/tex/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.c
ode.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
\pgfnodepartlowerbox=\box64
\pgfnodeparttwobox=\box65
\pgfnodepartthreebox=\box66
\pgfnodepartfourbox=\box67
\pgfnodeparttwentybox=\box68
\pgfnodepartnineteenbox=\box69
\pgfnodeparteighteenbox=\box70
\pgfnodepartseventeenbox=\box71
\pgfnodepartsixteenbox=\box72
\pgfnodepartfifteenbox=\box73
\pgfnodepartfourteenbox=\box74
\pgfnodepartthirteenbox=\box75
\pgfnodeparttwelvebox=\box76
\pgfnodepartelevenbox=\box77
\pgfnodeparttenbox=\box78
\pgfnodepartninebox=\box79
\pgfnodeparteightbox=\box80
\pgfnodepartsevenbox=\box81
\pgfnodepartsixbox=\box82
\pgfnodepartfivebox=\box83
))) (/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty
Package: preview 2017/04/24 13.1 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)
(/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf/tex/latex/preview/prtightpage.def
\PreviewBorder=\dimen259
)
\pr@snippet=\count305
\pr@box=\box84
\pr@output=\toks38
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-08-30 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count306
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box85
)
(./Untitled.aux)
\openout1 = `Untitled.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 43.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 43.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count307
\scratchdimen=\dimen260
\scratchbox=\box86
\nofMPsegments=\count308
\nofMParguments=\count309
\everyMPshowfont=\toks39
\MPscratchCnt=\count310
\MPscratchDim=\dimen261
\MPnumerator=\count311
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count312
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks40
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grfext/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2019/12/03 v1.3 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 504.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 45.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 45.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 45
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)
Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
./Untitled.tex:120: Undefined control sequence.
\pr@endbox ...fi \c@page =\pr@snippet \pr@shipout 
                                                  \ifpr@fixbb \hbox {\dimen@...
l.120 \end{page}
                
? 
./Untitled.tex:120: Emergency stop.
\pr@endbox ...fi \c@page =\pr@snippet \pr@shipout 
                                                  \ifpr@fixbb \hbox {\dimen@...
l.120 \end{page}
                
End of file on the terminal!

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17617 strings out of 475075
 366399 string characters out of 5779003
 708565 words of memory out of 5000000
 38692 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 472216 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 90i,9n,101p,411b,908s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
./Untitled.tex:120:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: compile ok for me. Show your log-file.

Comment: The original post was updated to include most of the log file.  The whole file wouldn't fit within the character limit.

Comment: a part of your files comes from a local texmf `/Users/salis1bt/Library/texmf`. I would suggest that you remove/rename that and try again with only the texlive 2022 files.

Comment: That fixed it -- thank you!